# Factorization some numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n,m>1$, b is any number.
Now, determine:

1) factorization for $b^n-1$

2) factorization for $b^n +1 $ where $n = 2k+1, k> 0$

3) factorization for $b^{nm} -1 $

Please give me an advice.

Comment: Note $b-1|b^n-1$, $b+1|b^n+1$ and $b^{nm}-1=(b^n)^m-(1^n)^m$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  for 1,2, think about what you know about factoring
$x^3 \pm y^3$.